# how to convert lits of ngrams into a representation that is acceptable for logistic regression like converting into vectors?

Tags: python-3.x, logistic-regression, n-gram, countvectorizer

I have a dataset that consist of list of ngrams for each sentencein the dataset like this and a tag for each sentence:

```
n-grams=[['thats', 'just', 'great', 'thats just', 'just great', 'thats just great'], 
       ['i', 'dont', 'thats', 'subscribe', 'just', 'to', 'either', 'i dont', 'dont thats', 'thats subscribe', 'subscribe just', 'just to', 'to either', 'i dont thats', 'dont thats subscribe', 'thats subscribe just'], 
       ['what', 'is', 'that', 'when', 'you', 'do', 'just']]

act_tags=tags['statement','statement','Wh_Question']
```

I want to apply logistic regression on n-grams as features and output as act tags. How should I convert the features input that is n-grams into vectorize form that is acceptable for logistic regression.